# Sonarqube is skipping some .csproj randomly in scanning

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube, static-analysis, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner

We have a solution(MVC .net project with c#) web.sln and we are having 11 projects in it. for example UI.csproj, API.csproj, and webservice.csproj.

We are using sonar scanner for MSBuild in the Azure DevOps server.

SonarQube works well sometimes for all the projects.
*The problem is*, many times it is skipping scan for some of .csproj. like we are unable to see UI.csproj in the report or some time API.csproj.

**Details-**
SonarQube server - 7.9 community Edition

If its a problem of server/scanner version then it shouldn't work even some times.
Can anyone please suggest?

Comment: So it correctly analyses all of the projects some of the time? If so, then one possible reason is incremental build i.e. MSBuild thinks it doesn't need to build a project because the project and its dependencies haven't changed.

Comment: @duncanp Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, it correctly analyses all the projects sometimes. but if it is an incremental build then  I should not get the project even I don't have change in it anything from a long time.